# SuspectScore in Email Headers

Tags: email, html-email, spam-prevention

I've Googled quite a bit and cannot find a definition to tell me what this means or how I can fix it.

I'm setting up some follow up emails, using mailgun.org as my SMTP provider and in the header I'm receiving this:

> X-Proofpoint-Spam-Details: rule=notspam policy=default score=0
>   spamscore=0 suspectscore=99 phishscore=0 adultscore=0 bulkscore=100
>   classifier=spam adjust=0 reason=mlx scancount=1
>   engine=7.0.1-1308280000 definitions=main-1310230044

All of that looks fine with the exception of `suspectscore=99` I can't find a definition for this, but it can't be a good thing to be a 99% suspect.

Anyone can enlighten me or point me to an accurate definition of `suspectscore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a header specific to a vendor product: [Proofpoint](http://www.proofpoint.com/).  You'll have to work with them to understand what's going on.

Comment: Yeah I've been all through their site.  No definitions that I can find.

Comment: Looks as though this is being marked up on the receiving side.  These headers appear in emails delivered to my iCloud account, but not my gmail account.

Comment: Yeah, it sure is on the receiver side.  I doubt Proofpoint will have public documentation on how to defeat their spam detection.  You might be able to "partner" with them, but I'll guess unless you're a big player with zillions of messages and a few thousand dollars to throw at their PS department, you won't get anywhere.

Comment: And, if someone has worked with them previously, it's most likely they're under NDA to prevent revealing the composition of the "secret sauce".

Comment: Ridiculous.  How are we supposed to become better marketers and good citizens we they won't even tell us we're doing incorrectly.  You can't just blankly assume everyone is up to no good.

Comment: Knock yourself out.  I do wish you luck.